# Simple array to objects with changing key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got a comma seperated list

`var arr = [1,2,3,4]`

and want it to be:

```
var new_arr = [
 {x:1, y:2},
 {x:3, y:4}
]
```

Struggeling how to get the key/value change done.

Comment: Loop over the array, grab two items from it each time, create a new object with x/y properties set to those values, and append to your result array ... (Btw., `new` is not a good name for a variable in JS, that will collide with the `new` keyword.)

Comment: What @CBroe said, but be careful to only loop until the second to last element. Taking two items on every step will throw an error on your very last step if you loop until the last element.

Comment: @Catalin-IoanNarita I did not mean two elements from every single index (1,2 - 2,3 - 3,4), but in _pairs_ of two (1,2 - 3,4). Simple `for` loop, that increments the loop counter by two instead of one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to return the desired result.

If the element index is even, add a new item to the result, if not skip it.

```js
const input = [1,2,3,4]
 
const result = input.reduce((acc, el, idx, arr) => { 
    return (idx % 2) ? acc : [...acc,  { x: el, y: arr[idx + 1]} ];
}, []);
 
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Terry Lennox and Jorge Guerreiro!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the below:

First you map over your array and if the `modulus value` of your current iteration index does not equal to 0, you return an empty object (which you will then `filter` out at the end), otherwise you return a new object that grabs the current element on the iteration to `y`, and the previous element of the array (using `index`) to `x`

```js
const x = [1,2,3,4,5]

const g = x.map((el, i) => {
  if(i%2) {
    return {
      x: x[i - 1],
      y: el
    }
  }
  return {}
}).filter(t => Object.keys(t).length)

console.log(g)
```